# NSArray and "If-statement"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I'm new at developing apps. I have a NSArray with 2 images in it.

```
imageOneArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"White.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Black.png"], nil];
```

My question is, is there a way to make an "if statement" that looks like this:

```
if ([imageOneArray = [UIImage imageNamed:@"White.png"]) {
    //DO SOMETHING
};
```

The code above is giving me error, how can i fix it? what am i doing wrong? what do i make it work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you to keep the name of images in the array like, `@[@"White.png", @"Black.png", ..]` and compare by `[[imageOneArray containsObject:@"White.png"]` and the element comparison will be easy by `isEqualToString:` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to check whether array **contains** an object you should go with

```
if ([imageOneArray containsObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"White.png"]]) {
    //DO SOMETHING
};
```

Here you should note, that array checks for containment sending `-isEqual:` to its objects. So, on the `UIImage` `-isEqual:` will do just pointers comparison. The above code will return `YES` due to image caching mechanism provided by `+imageNamed:`, however, in general, it should return `NO`. Consider following example:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"White" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSArray *arr = @[image1];
BOOL contains1 = [arr containsObject:image1]; // YES
BOOL contains2 = [arr containsObject:image2]; // NO
```

And consider the following example with strings:

```
NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithString:@"abc"];
NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithString:@"abc"];
NSArray *arr = @[string1];
BOOL contains1 = [arr containsObject:string1]; // YES
BOOL contains2 = [arr containsObject:string2]; // YES
```

So, you should keep in mind equality rules for objects in your array. There's brilliant article on this topic [Equality](http://nshipster.com/equality/) on NSHipster.

If you need to check whether array **is equal** to another array go with

```
if ([imageOneArray isEqualToArray:@[[UIImage imageNamed:@"White.png"]]]) {
    //DO SOMETHING
};
```

Take a look at [NSArray class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) to see when you can do with arrays

Comment: Thank you for the info. Now, why does it give me an error when I use containsObject? the error says: "No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'containsObject'"

Comment: You missed a colon probably... All above code compiles just fine

Answer (score 4):

You could try the following, assuming the goal was to check if the array contains an image named "White". Notice that UIImage -imageNamed: does not require the extension

```
if ([imageOneArray containsObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"White"]]) {
    //DO SOMETHING
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got a couple of problems in the code.

Firstly `"="` is an assignment e.g.

> `myName = Joe`

whereas "==" is comparison

> `1 == 1 (true) 1 == 2 (false)`

Secondly, an array contains multiple objects, so you would have to go through and compare each one (or use the containsObject method other answers include). You frequently would do that with a For loop.

```
UIImage* myImageToCompare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"White"];

for (int i=0; i<imageOneArray.count; i++) {
if ([imageOneArray objectAtIndex:i] == myImage){
...do something
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cab use containObject in the Array
-containsObject: compares the objects using -isEqual:, which is usually what you want: e.g., two NSString objects containing the same UNICODE characters would be considered equal, even if they are not the same object.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)doStuff{
    UIImage * const targetImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"White"];
    for (UIImage *currentImage in someArray /*replace someArray with your own*/) {
        if ([self image:targetImage isEqualTo:currentImage]) {
            // Do stuff
            break;
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)image:(UIImage * const)firstImage isEqualTo:(UIImage * const)secondImage {
    NSData * const firstData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(firstImage);
    NSData * const secondData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(secondImage);
    return [data1 isEqual:data2];
}
```